# Is an earth surface that is laid cement or tiles called "the ground"?

Tags: phrase-usage

In the dictionary,

> **[the ground](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ground_1?q=ground)**:  the solid surface of the earth

If I hear someone say "**she fell to the ground**", I picture the situation like this:

[image: woman fallen on her back onto grass]

If an area of the ground is laid cement or tiles, is it still called "**the ground**"?

[image: courtyard with an arrow pointing to a section of cement tiles, labeled "Is that called the ground?"]

For example, "*there are some tables and chairs on the ground*"

Comment: Those tables and chairs are on a paved area or 'patio'.

Comment: If a person falls on a cemented area, I would say that. I would not call it the ground. She fell on the cement and hurt her knee. However, the paper fell on the ground is ok for a cemented area. So, it all depends on **who and what is falling** or fell.

Comment: I wonder if it will be my friend....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, even if an area of the ground is covered with cement or tiles, like the area shown in your picture, it can still be referred to as "**the ground**". The term "**the ground**" generally refers to the solid surface of the earth, regardless of whether it is covered. So in your example sentence, it is still appropriate to say "there are some tables and chairs on **the ground**".

Comment: Indeed. And conversely, even a patch of dirt, if it's inside a walled structure, is "the floor" :)

Comment: Yes - **the ground** refers to _outdoors_.

Comment: @KateBunting - unfortunately, many British users call the outside surface the 'floor'.

Comment: The paper fell to the ground or on the ground. But, I fell on the cement and hurt my knee. Context is everything. However: When the bank robber was shot, he fell to the ground (could be the sidewalk, a walkway, etc.) The dictionary definition does not work here nor do generalities.

Comment: If it was a raised surface high above the general level (e.g. a raised patio, plaza, balcony, low roof, etc), I'd be reluctant to call it "ground" but this looks fairly level with the surrounding landscape.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Although there is a great deal of variability. For example, in the UK "dirt" means something that is soiled while "soil" as a noun is what you grow your garden in. Although of course at least one branch of English would describe that as a "yard".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've not heard "floor" used to represent the outside ground surface, and that includes cases where one is standing on a deck/patio etc. or in in a yard (i.e. a working/storage area, as distinct from what in the UK we'd call a garden) paved (i.e. covered with flagstones) or surfaced (with tarmac etc.).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - it is pretty common in such things as less formal newspaper stories, police reports of incidents, casual conversation, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not in my experience, but I'd hardly accuse those sources of speaking the King's English :-)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd "floor" as an informal term for an outside surface seems to me not uncommon, but mainly in children/young adults - and stably so for decades based on my experience in London years ago and elsewhere since

Comment: @LukeSawczak Even more so, a *roofed* structure (consider a walled garden)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - _The incident happened around 8pm on Friday near Pendle Wavelengths in Leeds Road when the victim was pushed in the back and fell to the floor._ Burnley Express 2 Dec 2014 _The Ecuadorian was chasing down a 50/50 ball after Addicks’ defender Jesurun Rak-Sakyi slipped in the box whilst in possession. Estupiñán dramatically fell to the floor, as Rak-Sakyi withdrew his foot at the last minute, highlighting the lack of contact made between the two players._ Sussex World 22 Dec 2022

Comment: _Christine Ranger, 74, was walking her dog along a cycle path near her home when she collided with the boy who was wearing a school uniform. The pensioner tumbled to the floor, while the young boy rode off, leaving her on the ground_ **[sic]**.  _Her daughter, Karen, said: "Mum was out walking the dog at around 3.15pm when she was hit by the boy on the e-scooter. He knocked her over and she face-planted the floor._ Daily Express Mar 27 2023

Comment: @ChrisH With emphasis on "informal". There's a parallel situation in at least some parts of the UK between "get out of the way!" and "get out of the road!".

Comment: In American speech, that's 100% incorrect.  Those tables and chairs are on a *patio*.  (That patio might be directly on the ground, or it might be on a slab which in on the ground.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, in the UK floor is indoors, ground is outdoors, but many journalists nowadays aren’t so good at English; I suspect you won’t be able to quote BBC, Guardian or say Financial Times journalists making this mistake. Then again, I’m getting old; maybe younger people are changing the language in the UK; I don’t talk to many youth nowadays :)

Comment: @minisaurus - How about this? _Nottinghamshire Police said the assault happened next to the Chesterfield Canal between the Lockkeeper pub and Rhodesia Bridge in Worksop, at about 11:30 GMT on 25 November. The victim was approached by a man who punched him and **pinned him to the ground after he fell to the floor**._ [BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-63867053) 6 December 2022 You could call that 'hedging your bet'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, what can I say? The Beeb's standards are obviously slipping :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "the ground" includes areas covered in tiles, stone, concrete, etc. For example, if I were standing around those tables and chairs and dropped something, I would say it "fell on the ground".

Although, *"There are some tables and chairs on the ground"* sounds odd. I think it's because tables and chairs outdoors are naturally "on the ground", so the only time we would actually say that is when they've been knocked over. Instead, if you want to talk about their location, I would refer to the area they're *in* or *on*, like **courtyard**, **patio**, **terrasse** (which is a Quebec thing; **terrace** might work instead), or **plaza**. Or if you want to refer to their position, you could say something like, "There are some tables and chairs **set up** outside (in the courtyard)".

---

For illustration, check out Saturday Night Live's [Threw It on the Ground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTgBfRTABs4) (NSFW). "The ground" is used to refer to sidewalks (of different materials) and what looks like a paved backyard. The only exception is inside the restaurant, where it would be "the floor" instead of "the ground".

Comment: You could say the furniture is _on the grounds_, which is similar in meaning to "on the premises" except usually implies an outdoor location.  It's more typical to be more explicit about the exact location, however.

Comment: @Miral completely different meaning IMO. As you say it means "the furniture is on the premises"